# How to replace value in list of lists - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, append

Hi everyone this is my first question , so please tell me how can I improve asking :),

I'm trying to run this code and I'm not getting the expected result .

i think the problem is that I'm editing values in list of lists

the code :

```
def f(x1,x2):
    return 1.5*(x1)**2+0.5*(x2**2)-x1*x2-2*x1
def f_tag_x1 (lst):
    x2=lst[1]
    x1=lst[0]
    return -((3*x1-x2-2)/3)
def f_tag_x2 (lst):
    x2=lst[1]
    x1=lst[0]
    return (x1-x2)
demsions=2
k=1
x=[[-2,4]]
ftags=[f_tag_x1,f_tag_x2]
while (k<3):
    x.append(x[k-1])
    for i in range(0,demsions):
        if i==0:
            x[k][i]=(x[k-1][i]+ftags[i](x[k-1]))
        else:
            x[k][i]=(x[k][i]+ftags[i](x[k]))
    k=k+1
    
        
print(x)
```

instead of the results of all the runs in one list
i just get the same value ( the last one )
in all the list

for example :
i get
[[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]

instand of

[[e, r], [h, j], [x, y]]

i think it is because im using x[k][i] to get each element inside the lists and its messing it up
but i cant find another way to do it

thanks in advance !

i have try to use x[k][i] as an easy access to edit a list of lists but it doesn't work so good

Answer (score 0):

This is because `x.append(x[k - 1])` appends the same list every time, so every change to one sublist changes all of them. Append a copy instead

```
while k < 3:
    x.append(x[k - 1][:])
    ...

print(x) # [[-2, 4], [2.0, 2.0], [1.3333333333333335, 1.3333333333333335]]
```